# Is the function bounded each petal consider to be continuous when n tend to infinity?

Tags: continuity, matlab, chain-rule

Was plotting this graph in matlab on the cartesian axis(x,y) and $0<t<2\pi$,this function will generate 2n "petal" depend on the input number n.

$x=r.cos(t)$

$y=r.sin(t)$

$r=2.sin(nt)$

As example n=10, noticed the curve bounded each petal is continuous and by using chain rule, the derivative found

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}.\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{n.sin(t).cos(nt)+sin(nt).cos(t)}{n.cos(t).cos(nt)-sin(nt)sin(t)}$

[image]

Then I consider n=1000 which is what I get

[image]

After enlarge the edge, noticed each curve as if squeeze into a pointy line

[image]

When n is large, the derivative become

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{n.sin(t).cos(nt)+sin(nt).cos(t)}{n}}{\frac{n.cos(t).cos(nt)-sin(nt)sin(t)}{n}}\approx tan(t)$

Now I am confused regarding the concept of continuity, I read on internet for a function f(x) if it is differentiable at c then it is continuous at C but at the same time, from internet I also get to know "pointy line" is not differentiable. So for this function when n tend to infinity, the line bounded each petal still consider to be continuous? as its derivative exist but at the same time each of them is a pointy line?

Comment: The petal is continuous and not pointy, but you'll need greater magnification to see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ivan Neretin has pointed out, you are only seeing "pointy lines" because you haven't enlarged enough. Magnify more and you will eventually see smooth turn-arounds instead of points, similar to what you see in the $n =10$ graph, though with straighter sides.

For any *finite* $n$ you will find the same holds. The higher $n$ is, the smaller the radius-of-curvature of the turn-around, and thus the more magnification will be needed to not see it as a point, but that radius-of-curvature will still be $> 0$, so at some magnification, it will appear smooth.

What happens when you let $n \to \infty$? You cease to have a curve. $r = \sin n\theta$. If $n = \infty$, this no longer makes sense. For a fixed angle $\theta$, as $n \to \infty$ the values of $r$ do not approach a single limit, but many different limit points. When $\theta$ is an irrational multiple of $\pi$, $r$ will approach every value in $[-1,1]$. For rational multiples of $\pi$, there will be only a finite number of limit points. Letting $n \to \infty$ does not result in a curve, so no results about the behavior of curves are applicable.

Comment: Understood.How about the last part $\frac{dy}{dx}=tan(t)$? Does that imply when n tend to infinity, the curve actually converge to a single line so $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is define as the gradient of the line at t?

Comment: If you watch a movie of these graphs as $n$ increases, it will look like the pedals migrate towards $\theta = 0$, so you have be specific about what you mean by the limit of a single pedal. Given a value of $\theta$, if you choose for each $n$ the pedal of which $\theta$ is part, it will converge *as a set* to the line segment $r = \theta, -1\le r \le 1$ (the pedal at $\theta$ will keep flipping sides as $n$ increases). As a curve it will not converge because the domain of the pedals shrink to $[\theta, \theta]$.